# XMLHttpRequest status undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have some problems whith my code below:

```js
function fetchgraphdata()
{
 var xmlhttp_1;

 var urls = "xml_gen_graph.jsp";
 console.log("Url Formed = " + urls);

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp_1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else {
  xmlhttp_1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp_1.open("POST",urls, true);
 xmlhttp_1.send();
 xmlDoc = xmlhttp_1.responseXML;

 xmlhttp_1.onreadystatechange = function ()
 {
  if (xmlhttp_1.readyState === 4)
  {
   console.log("Graph data is ready");
   z = 0;
   xmlDoc = xmlhttp_1.responseXML; // xmlhttp_1.responseXML.childNodes;
   x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("day");
   y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("consp");
   while (xmlDoc !== null)
   {
    date_1 = x[z].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    consp_1 = y[z].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    console.log("date = " + date_1 + " Consumption = " + consp_1);
    z++;
   }
  }
 };

}
```

Problems:

1. Sometime `xmlhttp_1.status` -> `return` -> `undefined`
2. Sometime `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property getElementsByTagName` of null.
3. Sometime it gives correct output.

Can someone help me?

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Comment: Why are you trying to read the responseXML before the request completes?

Comment: how to make sure that request got completed. if I try to check xmlhttp_1.status-> it gives out "undefined"